# Downloading AND installing .mobileconfig in Safari - Not installing - OS X (not iOS)

Tags: php, configuration, mobile-safari, profile, provisioning

In our app, we direct the user to download a .mobileconfig.  Originally the problem was Safari just displayed the XML rather than downloaded that, but we got around this with a PHP script (below).

```
<?php
$file = "http://example.com/myProfile.mobileconfig"; 
header("Content-Description: File Transfer"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\""); 
readfile ($file); 
?>
```

However we commonly see it where the .mobileconfig is downloaded and automatically it brings up the 'do you wish to install page'.  How is that done?  Are we missing something in Content-Type?
Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same problem, the solution is below.
Just set the content type, works like a charm ;)

```
public function controllerMethod() {
    // $config contains generated XML file as string.
    $config = $this->generateConfig('apple', Input::all());

    // Make response -> attach $config to response
    $response = Response::make($config);
    // Set headers
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-apple-aspen-config');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename='mail.mobileconfig'");

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the reply, but no luck yet.  So far, I have got: `<?php
$file = "http://freedom-apps.com/armour/config.mobileconfig";

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/x-apple-aspen-config");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");

readfile ($file);
?>`    and this still does not work - the certificate is just downloaded, not opened in System Preferences.  I am testing with Safari.  Any idea what is going on?  Thanks!

Comment: I added my complete solution with some comments for better understanding.

Comment: Can I check you are doing this on Mac OS X, and not iOS?  I tried this, and am still getting just the file downloading in Safari on Mac and not opening in System Preferences automatically.  Sam

Comment: Yeah, I do it on Mac. I do create mail profile, which after downloading configures Mail app on OS X and iOS as well. This profile is the same for both of them. Work on both of them for me after adding headers.

Comment: Thnx this totally worked, I used it in my Vue JS script. Returned my data with `data:application/x-apple-aspen-config;charset=utf-8,`